# Can I average the BERT embeddings of multiple instances of the same word to get one vector representation of the word?

Tags: word-embeddings, bert, corpus

In the project I'm working on right now I would like to get one embedding for every unique lemma in a corpus. Could I get this by averaging the embeddings of every instance of a lemma?

For example, say that there were 500 tokens of the lemma "walk" - regardless of conjugation - could I then add/average/concatenate these 500 embeddings together to get one embedding accurately representing all of them?

If this would work, which operation should I use on the embeddings to get the best result?

Comment: How are you getting 500 embeddings for the same lemma?

Comment: Not for the same lemma, 1 embedding per token of the same word, regardless of conjugation. I would like to combine these embeddings into one.

Comment: You cant have multiple embeddings of the same word, BERT will generate one per word

Comment: What do you mean? When I run BERT over a sentence containing two instances of the same word, for example: "When I was driving my car I also saw another car", the vectors of the two tokens "car" will be different.